# C++ Makefile on "complex" tree structure

Tags: c++, makefile

I have found a lot of related questions, but I was still not able to make my own Makefile.
This makefile is using Mingw64 on Windows, and I want it to run on *nix, currently Debian, but I would like to be able to make it run on Alpine too, as it's used in a Docker container.

The project tree structure is something like :

```cpp
./
  src/
    main.cpp
    Server.cpp <- use asio and Utils/Split.h
    Server.h   <- use asio
    Utils/
      Split.h
  lib/
    asio/include/ <- asio library (without boost, header only)
  Makefile <- That is what I am trying to do right now
  Dockerfile
```

I tried multiple things, here is my latest Makefile (that obviously, does not work) :

```sh
NAME        := GameServer
CXX         := g++
CXXFLAGS    := -std=c++2a -DASIO_STANDALONE

SRC_DIR     := ./src
LIBS        := -I lib/asio-1.18.1/include \
               -I lib/rapidjson-1.1.0/include \
               -I src

rwildcard   = $(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

SRCS        := $(call rwildcard,$(SRC_DIR),*.cpp)
OBJS        := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

.PHONY: all

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

Note: the code (.cpp, .h) is valid, it's coming from an already-running project, but built on Visual Studio (compiled with MSVC).

Here are the two functions done my mingw32-make :

```
g++ -c -o src/Server.o src/main.cpp -I lib/asio/include -I src
g++ -o Server src/main.o src/Server.o
```

First line : It should builds the .o from the .cpp and adds the include to asio. I added `-I src` to add src/Utils, but I guess that's not the way of doing it ?
Second line : It should (link ?) the two .o in a single file : the executable.

The errors I am getting with this makefile are :

- `src/Server.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x36): multiple definition of 'main'`, `src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x36): first defined here` (and this, for every .o)
- `src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to 'Server::Server()'` (and this, for every Server methods main calls, even some from asio)
  They appears when the second g++ line starts (`g++ -o Server src/main.o src/Server.o`)

So here are my questions :

1. What am I doing wrong ?
2. Is there a better way of trying to make a development environment on Windows and still be able to copy the project in a Docker container (and then compile it with the gcc image) to build it with the same Makefile ?

Sorry if I forgot to mention some details, I am new with Mingw and its environment.

Thank you

Edit : Corrected version :

```sh
NAME        := GameServer
CXX         := g++
CXXFLAGS    := -std=c++1z

SRC_DIR     := ./src
LIBS        := -lwsock32 -lws2_32 \
               -I lib/asio-1.18.1/include \
               -I lib/rapidjson-1.1.0/include \
               -I src

rwildcard   = $(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

SRCS        := $(call rwildcard,$(SRC_DIR),*.cpp)
OBJS        := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

.PHONY: all

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

$(OBJS): $(SRC_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

Comment: `g++ -c -o src/Server.o src/main.cpp` This is done incorrectly causing the next line linking two object files of main.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the rule...

```
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

This tells `make` that *all* items in `$(OBJS)` depend on *all* items in `$(SRCS)`.  But the command...

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

...always compiles the first dependency as identified by `$<`.  It just so happens that in your case `$<` is `src/main.cpp`.

Instead you should probably use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) such as...

```
$(SRC_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

You can also limit the scope of that rule to only those targets specified by `$(OBJS)` with a full [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)...

```
$(OBJS): $(SRC_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Just for clarification, the first example is not a _static_ pattern rule, it's just a pattern rule.  The second example is a static pattern rule.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my issues, I still have one though : `./src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS1_4dataEhh[_ZN4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS1_4dataEhh]+0x7a): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'`. I am using standalone version of Asio, so am I missing something ?

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed, edited and thanks for the correction.  Let me know if it still needs 'work'.

Comment: @Lucas Re. `undefined reference to __imp_WSAStartup` you might want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559028/undefined-reference-to-imp-wsacleanup).

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it, just added in LIB variable : -lwsock32 -lws2_32